# How to put offset in bootstrap4 beta

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How to put offset in bootstrap4 beta. `col-offset-"offset value"` is not working for me. How can I solve this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`col-{selector}-offset-{value}` has been replaced with `ml-auto` or `mr-auto` class, depending on which side you want for `margin` to start.

You should read the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns) next time when trying out new versions of frameworks.

Answer (score -1):

We dont do offset instead we give a margin , bootstrap 4 uses flex so its a little bit different from previous versions alpha-4 included.
we use  .mt-auto to give remaining coloums for margin or else we can do different margin for different screen sizes

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 ml-auto">.col-md-4 .ml-auto</div>
</div>
```

It's there in the bootstrap 4 beta documentation
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns

Comment: That's the alpha, not [beta documentation](http://getbootstrap.com)

Comment: This was deprecated in `Bootstrap v4 beta` , `offset-md` was only available in `Bootstrap v4 alpha`.

Comment: @VladimirJovanović My bad i changed the answer

Comment: @ZimSystem sorry totally left my mind.